# Cross compile libzip for windows

Tags: c++, linux, mingw, cross-compiling, libzip

I am on linux and I can cross complie libzip I edited cmakeList and add the standard stuff
and I did not generate the .dll.a i used mingw32 I get only .a i need .dll.a

```
Host os :linux
Target:Windows
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you add CMake flag `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON`? This is needed to build DLL (= shared library on Windows).

Comment: yes but no change